# Link to Code Automatic

Tags: php, html

I have lots of PDF files that I scan daily. I also have my own website.

Here's its **index.html**:

```
<html>
  <body>This is my site and docs</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to ask if a code could be made for creating a link in the code of **index.html** body when I add a file on the FTP server. Currently I am using Filezilla.

It means that if I upload a **.pdf** on the server in some specific folder, it should automatically write in the **index.html**.

```
<a href = "filename.pdf">filename</a>
```

Is there an addon for this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You write a server side API to fetch the list of documents, get the data via ajax, and then update your html with this data

Comment: Storing the file names/locations in a database would make sense. Are you doing that? You had mysql tagged but I see nothing about databases here..

Comment: @chris85 no need I got an answer thankd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = scandir(__DIR__);
$files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..'));

foreach ($files as $file) {

    echo "<a href='" . $file . "'>" . $file . "</a><br>";
}
```

1. Scan dir
2. Remove the dots
3. Output the files into the page and maybe add a link

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: can u fill the required things with raw data and then reply plz

Comment: @harshbansal This should be the answer. Just modify the `echo` to be a link. Use the `http` there no reason for FTPing here.

Comment: i am not getting links instead names only....tell me plz how to configure....i mean code line