# Link to Code Automatic with Custom Text

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, ftp

I had last time asked that how to get an automatic generated link on the body of website of file uploaded on ftp-server. 
Link is this [Link to Code Automatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561390/link-to-code-automatic).

But my father wanted that it should not display the filename. Instead it should display that name that he would feed on some other page.

My main storyline is that when i go to that page, it asks me to enter a name that is to be displayed and next to it after `<br>`, it should give a dropdown menu of the files on the ftp-server and ask me to select the one for which i gave the name. Further on submitting, it displays the link to the file with the name i game.

Kindly help me solve this problem because i am a beginner at PHP and SQL.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to be able to enter the displayed name of one file or the names of all the files in the directory?

Comment: plz explain what u r talking of

Comment: So, just to clarify: on the first page, the user can choose what name should be displayed, and what file the link should point at, using a dropdown. On the second page, the link is displayed. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes just entering that name

Comment: peter r u giving an answer?

Comment: Yes I'm working on it

Comment: thanks  for support

Answer (score 1):

For the first page, use what was suggested in the first question, but use a HTML `select` instead:

```php
<?php
// page1.php
// ...

// create a form element
echo '<form action="page2.php" method="get">';
// create the 'name' input
echo 'Enter the displayed name: <input name="name" placeholder="displayed name"><br />';

// start the dropdown
echo 'Enter the file the link should point to: <select name="file">';

// get all files that should be displayed
$files = scandir(__DIR__);
$files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..'));

foreach ($files as $file) {
  // add an option to the dropdown
  echo '<option value="' . $file . '">' . $file . '</option>';
}

// close the dropdown and the form
echo '</select>';

// add a submit button to the form
echo '<button type="submit">Submit</button>';

echo '</form>';

// ...
?>
```

On the second page, display the link:

```php
<?php
// page2.php
// ...
$name = $_GET['name'];
$file = $_GET['file'];
echo '<a href="' . $file . '">' . $name. '</a><br>';
// ...
?>
```

Comment: Buddy you forget to add submit in the page1.php

Comment: Thanks once again

Comment: The Submit tag isnt working...nothing being displayed like button. And Plz add redirection to Submit Button to go to Page2.php

Comment: One more prob. Page 2 Displays only one record and when i close the browser, everything erases. You can also give me code in MySQL if needed or i can ask these questions again. Thanks. Waiting for Reply.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I put the submit button in the select element. Your other problem: isn't it supposed to only display one record? And if you close the browser, it should be erased, right? Do you want to remember the user's inputs and display them when he or she comes back?

Comment: yes ... thats the main motive. I add I see i again add i again see 2 rec and i close i reopen i see 2 rec...so on ... like this

Comment: Are you adding the answer!

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have to figure this out yourself or ask another Stackoverflow question. You have to store the user's selection in the database.

Comment: plz help me Buddy ply it's  a request . Plz tell MySQL code

Comment: My friend, as much as I want to help you, how should I be able to do so? I don't know the structure of your MySQL database, I don't exactly know what the result show be. Plan your programs before you write them, and if you don't know where to start, maybe some tutorials can help you. Your issue is too broad to be discussed here in the comments.